# Overriding the dynamic linker path?

Tags: linux, linker, qemu

I'm running Linux on an x86_64 system.  I have a Raspbian image mounted on `/mnt`.  If I want run binaries under `/mnt`, I can `chroot` into the Rasbpian environment and the system will use `qemu-arm-static` to run the armhf binaries.

I can run a *single* binary outside of the `chroot` environment doing something like this:

```
qemu-arm -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ \
  /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /mnt/bin/echo hello world
```

But is there a way to override the dynamic linker path (in this case, `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`) such that the first process can start additional arm binaries? For example, starting a shell works fine:

```
outside$ qemu-arm -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ \
  -E PATH=/mnt/bin:/mnt/usr/bin \
  /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /mnt/bin/sh
$ echo hello world
hello world
```

But trying to spawn another binary fails:

```
$ ls
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
```

Can I convince the kernel to find the dynamic linker (for arm binaries) in `/mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` without running in a chroot'd environment?

Comment: Hmm, there is some interesting discussion on this topic [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host), and it looks like the answer is "no, you can't do that". In fact, I think I'm going to close this as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: That other question is about running a program natively, where indeed it isn't all that easy to do that. For QEMU, you can use the QEMU_LD_PREFIX environment variable to specify a directory where guest file operations should look first, which will include where the dynamic linker is looked for. The catch is that a long-standing bug in QEMU means that right now if you point -L at a full chroot directory it will hang, because it can't cope with symlinks in the directory. But it will work for a restricted sysroot setup.

Comment: I had actually started fiddling with `-L` before posting this question, but as you say, for this particular purpose (in which I have mounted a complete OS image) it simply doesn't work...which makes the solution here just another "how I run multiple glibcs" question. Is there an existing bug report for the `QEMU_LD_PREFIX` issue with symlinks?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1245703 (there's a link at the bottom to a patch which has a plan for fixing it, though that patch has some issues)

Comment: Thanks! He said, adding words to make stackoverflow happy...